# nginx rewrite url not working

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I'm trying to add a new location to my nginx configuration. I set up ngix accorting to [this webpage](http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/). Now I think the most important line for me in the config file is this one:

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

So it includes all config files that are inside the `sites-enabled` folder. For now I have a default and a default-ssl config file.

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;
    root       /var/www/;

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default-ssl.access.log  main;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      ssl/localhost.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/localhost.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
    }

    location = /info {
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
        rewrite (.*) /.info.php;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

Now I want to add a new subfolder `redux`. I tried it with this config part:

```
location = /redux {
            rewrite (.*) /redux/index.php;
        }
```

But it does not work at all, I only get this error message:

```
015/09/15 10:10:41 [error] 844#0: *7 "/var/www/redux/user/login/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "POST /redux/user/login/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/redux/"
```

But what I expected is, that the /user/login part is given to the index.php under redux/index.php as parameter.

What do I need to change?

My .htaccess looked like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(Templates|cache|uploads)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

My final solution which works looks like this:

```
location /redux/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /redux/index.php?$args;
    include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
}
```